# generation of sine wave with ad5686 using raspberry pi through SPI communication

Tags: raspberry-pi-os

I am using an AD5686 DAC which is connected to the raspberry pi through SPI communication with CE1 (GPIO7). I have to generate a sine wave using the DAC. But I am not able to do it. Please help me. Here is the code i used.

```
import spidev
import time
import math
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(13, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.output(13, GPIO.HIGH)
GPIO.setup(7, GPIO.OUT)
CE1_PIN = 7  # CE1 is connected to GPIO 7

# Open SPI bus
spi = spidev.SpiDev()
spi.open(0, 1)
spi_max_speed = 4 * 1000000 # 4 MHz
spi.max_speed_hz = spi_max_speed

# Function to send data to AD5686
def send_data(data):
    spi.xfer2(data)

# Function to set CE1 pin
def set_ce1(state):
    GPIO.output(CE1_PIN, state)

# Function to set DAC output value
def set_dac_value(channel, value):
    # Set CE1 pin low to select AD5686
    set_ce1(0)
    # Dictionary to map channel labels to channel addresses
    channel_addresses = {'A': 0x30, 'B': 0x34, 'C': 0x38, 'D': 0x3C}
    # Get the channel address
    channel_byte = channel_addresses[channel]
    # DAC value (16-bit)
    dac_value = int(value * 65535 / 3.50)
    # DAC command byte
    dac_command_byte = channel_byte | ((dac_value >> 12) & 0x0F)
    # DAC data bytes
    dac_data_bytes = [(dac_value >> 8) & 0xFF, dac_value & 0xFF]
    # Send command and data bytes
    send_data([dac_command_byte] + dac_data_bytes)
    # Set CE1 pin high to release AD5686
    set_ce1(1)


# Function to generate sine wave
def generate_sine_wave(duration, frequency):
    sample_rate = 1000000  # Sample rate (Hz)
    num_samples = int(duration * sample_rate)
    for i in range(num_samples):
        # Calculate sine wave value
        value = math.sin(2 * math.pi * frequency * i / sample_rate)
        # Set DAC output value
        set_dac_value('A', value)
        set_dac_value('B', value)
        set_dac_value('C', value)
        set_dac_value('D', value)

        # Small delay between samples
        time.sleep(1 / sample_rate)

# Main function
if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        # Generate sine wave with duration 1 second and frequency 1 Hz
        generate_sine_wave(100, 10000)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        # Ctrl+C pressed, cleanup GPIO
        spi.close()
        GPIO.output(13, GPIO.HIGH)
```